# reload flag with uvicorn: can we exclude certain code?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

Is it somehow possible to exclude certain part of the code when reloading the scrip with `--reload` flag?

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

Use case: I have a model which takes a lot of time loading so I was wondering if there is a way to ignore that line of code when reloading. Or is it just impossible?

Comment: we just pushed https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/pull/820 which makes it possible

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update**

Uvicorn now supports including/excluding certain directories/files to/from watchlist.

```
  --reload-include TEXT           Set glob patterns to include while watching
                                  for files. Includes '*.py' by default, which
                                  can be overridden in reload-excludes.
  --reload-exclude TEXT           Set glob patterns to exclude while watching
                                  for files. Includes '.*, .py[cod], .sw.*,
                                  ~*' by default, which can be overridden in
                                  reload-excludes.
```

---

No there is no way to exclude something, however you can be explicit in what you want to be looked at with the `--reload-dir` flag:

```
  --reload-dir TEXT               Set reload directories explicitly, instead
                                  of using the current working directory.
```

in https://www.uvicorn.org/#command-line-options

Comment: Could you advise on how to exclude asterik-symbol.json using this method while preserving the reload functionality?  I tried: 
uvicorn main:app --reload-exclude 'asterik-symbol.json' 

however it generated this warning: 
WARNING:  Current configuration will not reload as not all conditions are met, please refer to documentation.  (Note: I typed asterik-symbol in place of asterik which wasn't displaying in the comment)

Comment: @STEMFabLab, for what it's worth, I have a similar issue. I hope to track/resolve it via https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2722.

Comment: @euri10, what does, "No there is no way to exclude something," mean? What is the `--reload-exclude` option for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible, when a server reloads it loads all the needed files into memory from scratch. It doesn't keep the memory of the previous launch.

Answer (score 0):

--reload-dir option is available. It will set reload directories explicitly, instead of using the current working directory.

```
 --reload-dir
```